# Use KIE WorkBench create a bpmn2 file after I save it,it has occurs messy code

Tags: jbpm

Recently I have met a messy code problem when I use JBPM's KIE WorkBench
The KIE WorkBench Version is `6.4.0.Final`

The language what I use is Chinese.

While I editor the file, it looks like correct.
After I save the file and reopen the bpmn2 file,it occurs messy code problem.

Is there anyone have met the same problem, and knew how to solve the problem,please help me.Thank you

There I have a picture to describe the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in the upcoming jBPM 6.5. Try to use version 6.5.0.CR2 to verify if it works. You can expect final version in a few weeks.